# Spring Hadoop: logging from own mappers/reducers

Tags: java, spring, logging, hadoop, log4j

I'm basically running Spring Hadoop exapmple from: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hadoop-samples/tree/master/mapreduce

Difference is, that I have my own mapper and reducer classes.

**My question is, how can I see logs from my mapper/reducer?**

Using log4j.properties I can change logging level for org.apache.hadoop and org.springframework.data.hadoop classes and it's working fine.

I am not able to enable logs from my classes.

Answer (score 0):

Mapper and Reduer logs can be viewed via JobTracker web interface:

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.19.0/quickstart.html